# sql optimize a query using the join

Tags: sql

I have a table productHistory

```
productHistory (id_H , id_product , name , tsInsert);
```

I wanna get from the table productHistory the last product in the giving period (start, end):
tsInsert must be between the start and the end.

I can do like this:

```
select max(id_H) 
from productHistory 
where tsInsert>=:start and tsInsert <=:end 
group by id_product;
```

then select all from productHistory  where id_H in the previous selection.

This query is very heavy, is there any other solution using the right join for example?

Comment: Your statement is as good as it gets. All I can suggest to "optimize" is to add proper indexes on your tables. What DBMS are you using? Can you post a query plan?

Comment: By "very heavy" do you mean that execution time is to long?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM productHistory  x

    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  MAX(id_H) as maxId
        FROM productHistory 
        GROUP id_product
    ) y

ON x.id_H = y.maxId
and x.TSINSERT >=:start and x.TSINSERT <=:end
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer your own question with an addition to your question. Please *edit* your question and add the additional information. Also try to add an execution plan and add what DBMS you are using.

Comment: but that is my solution

Comment: lol, my mistake but I doubt this returns what you need. Consider following two rows `id_h, id_product, tsInsert`: `1, 99, 01/01/2000` and `2, 99, 01/01/1990` and your `:start` being > 1990 will return **no rows**.

Comment: I can't see what's the pb with this query?

Comment: I was trying to create a Fiddle but the site seems to be down but in a nutshell: from my example, would you expect `id_h `1 to be returned when querying for `:start` > 1990 or not?

Comment: if the :end >01/01/2000, it should be returned

Comment: You solution wouldn't return that row, that was the point I was trying to make.